# Are smart quotes always legal in XML regardless of encoding?

Tags: xml, unicode, character-encoding

I read that smart quotes can be represented in XML as

```
 &#x2019; &#x2018;
```

The part I'm not clear about is: when encoded that way, are they always legal in the XML document, regardless of the encoding being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes,** `&#x2019;` (aka RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) `&#x2018;` (aka LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) are ***[allowed characters in XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets)*** :

> ```
> [2] Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
> ```

This does not depend upon the chosen character encoding, but it does depend upon the character appearing where `Char` allows.  So, for example, it may not be used to delimit attribute values or within the names of elements or attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding determines how the binary data of the file is converted into the characters that make up XML source code.

The characters you listed to create the character references (ampersand, the letter x, etc) are ones which appear in *every* encoding.

Since the characters appear in every encoding, you can use them no matter what encoding you are using.

Being able to represent characters that don't appear in the encoding the XML source code is using is one of the advantages of using characer references.

Comment: This is a helpful explanation but to be complete must be adjusted to account for `&`, `#`, `x`, `0`, and `;` also appearing in all encodings, yet `&#0;` most definitely *not* being legal in XML.  (Your explanation presents necessary but not sufficient conditions to determine the legality of `&#x2019;` and `&#x2018;` in XML.)